# How does .net MVC controller parse the arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I recently published a new version of my [Advanced Controller](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/353260/ASP-NET-Advanced-Generic-Handler-ASHX)

This is basically a Generic Controller (ASHX) that acts, on ASP.net Webforms, like an MVC controller in a sense that it receives a request and automatically invokes the desired inner method, parses its arguments from the request querystring or params depending on the HTTP verb and returns the result.
It does a lot more but this was me main initial functionality.

The object creation and hydration from the request information was the most painful part of the project but at the end I reached similar performance as the same request done to an MVC controller.

Like I said, .net MVC Controllers actually do the same but I never managed to get to know how.

For instance, if I do this AJAX call to an MVC Controller:

```
$.ajax({
     type:'GET',
     url: 'SomeData/List'
     data:{filter: 'whatever'}
});
```

This will call a controller method that receives a String filter property.

But it can get more complex as we can call Controllers that receive Complex Types, with nested Complex Types and Collections and "magically" the arguments appear correctly parsed in the controller arguments.

Does anyone know how this plumbing is done in .net MVC?

Comment: Check out the [DefaultModelBinder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultmodelbinder%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Comment: nothing magic. This is called Model binding. You can google for that ,or look for example at http://www.howmvcworks.net/OnModelsAndViewModels/TheBeautyThatIsTheModelBinder

Comment: Model Binding. Have a read over here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx

Answer (score 4):

This process is called Model Binding. There's a default Model Binder that will try to convert posted values to a complex type by looking at what's in the request and what the controller expects.

It does this based on conventions. Obviously the views also implement this convention so have you no friction when using the views and controllers with the Model Binder.

The following posts explain the concept in more detail:

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx
http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/05/05/iterating-on-an-asp-net-mvc-model-binder.aspx
http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Model_Binders_in_ASPNET_MVC.aspx

If you google for "ASP.NET MVC model binder", you will find a lot more information on the subject.

Comment: Ok, maybe the word "Magic" wasn't the most appropriate :)
What I mean is that we can't use it outside the ControllerContext can we? Is there a way to only use that code without the whole MVC infrastructure?